# XML tags missing in payload of cloudhub notification

Tags: xml, mule, anypoint-studio, cloudhub

We are using cloudhub notification to receive a mail alert whenever there is an exception. We are including XML payload as part of email message. We are getting the mail but XML tags are missing.

**Configuration**:

```
<cloudhub:create-notification   domain="${mule.cloudhub.domain}"
          config-ref="Cloudhub" message="#[payload]"
          priority="ERROR"      doc:name="Cloudhub"/>
```

**Expected**:

```
<books>
  <book>
    <title>title1</title>
    <price>price1</price>
  </book>
 </books>
```

**Actual**:

```
  title1 price1
```

Comment: Your not showing enough of your config so it's impossible to help you. For instance, what is the payload type? Is it a DOM object? If yes, then what you experience is normal.

Comment: @David my payload type is java.lang.String. When I print a logger it is printing XML properly.

Comment: This is weird then, I've checked the source code and if the payload is string, then it should be sent as-is. What about the receiving end? Maybe the body has the tags but whatever is viewing the email thinks it's HTML and removes the tags?

Comment: @David I tried using outlook and gmail clients. In both the cases its same. While in gmail I observed that mail is getting triggered from cloudhub-noreply@mulesoft.com via amazonses.com . Do you think it has any significance ?

Comment: Ah possibly, yes. SES may not like this kind of bodies :(

Answer (score 0):

This is just a workaround i did. Not sure whether its the correct method, but it works for me.Add

> ```
> &lt;expression-component doc:name="Expression"&gt;&lt;![CDATA[payload=payload.replace('>','&#38;gt;');
>     payload=payload.replace('<','&#38;lt;');]]>&lt;/expression-component &gt;
> ```

before the cloudhub connector to change the payload so that the `xml` escape characters are applied

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when trying to open XML files in Chrome and IE.  I found that if the XML file was too big (such as 37 megs), the file would open, but the XML tags would be missing.  It would only show the data within the tags.  For example, I expected it to appear like this in the browsers:

```
<ns0:quality>17</ns0:quality>
<ns0:duration>900</ns0:duration>
```

But, it would appear as

```
17900
```

in the browsers.  Thee solution was to decrease the size of the XML file, and then the tags appeared.  (Also, I've seen it happen if the computer is low on memory, which is fixed by a reboot.)